# Mockito.doNothing is calling the real method

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito

I have a class which uses another class.

```
Class A {

public B b;

A(){
 b = new B()
}
fun methodA(){
method1()
}

}

Class B {

String name

public void method1(){
   someMethod()
}

public void someMethod(){
 Log.d("this method gets called")

}
}


A a = new A()
B b = spy(a.b)
doNothing.when(b).somethod()

a.methodA() // This still calls someMethod()
```

doNothing doesn't work in Hierachy. Can anyone please help.

Comment: There are a few things you could do to get this example easier on the eyes: 1. format your code 2. remove typos. 3. keep it in one programming language

Answer (score 1):

You created a spy, but your object `a` still points to the original instance of `b`, not to the newly-created spy.

Try:

```
A a = new A();
B bSpy = spy(a.b);
doNothing().when(bSpy).someMethod();
a.b = bSpy;

a.methodA();
```